# Ubuntu Shell Script Output Directory

Tags: bash, output, directory

I don't use bash much, but lately I've had to use it and I have been continuously running into an issue with command-line arguments, specifically output directories. Some example code below:

Running:

```
log2timeline -f win7 -z EST5EDT -r -p -o csv -w /home/sansforensics/Desktop/PATH/file /mnt/hgfs/DRIVE/INPUT
```

on the command line works exactly as expected, the -w flag signifies the output path/file and that is exactly where it ends up, on the user's desktop in the PATH folder.

But when I run it from a .sh file sitting on the Desktop of the same user, i.e.

```
sudo bash test.sh
```

and all the file contains is the same exact command, the output file does not show up in the expected location. What am I missing here??

Comment: what about chmod +x test.sh and then run it like ./test.sh ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried that, but same thing - nothing shows up in the output dir.

Comment: do you provide your directoies like arguments for the script?

Comment: The output directory is the -w flag in the line of bash, the '/home/sansforensics/Desktop/PATH/file'. So when running it on the terminal it works fine, but when the same line is ran through a .sh script, it doesn't.

Comment: try to change your script a little bit and provide your paths as parameters, ./test.sh "path" "path". And in the script change your paths as "$1" and "$2". And you don't need sudo and bash if you running it like ./test.sh with proper rights

Comment: Yeah but the thing is I eventually want to list a bunch of these to run so that I don't have to be at the terminal to kick them off, so I'm trying to get it to work straight from the shell script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67073/discussion-between-ballpython-and-djmccarthy12).